# Modular multiplicative inverse

Tags: c, number-theory

I calculating ((A^B)/C)%M, but my code is not working when A,B,C,M are large in numbers. This code is giving right answer when A,B,C,D is small `int`.

What is wrong here?

**Here C and M is co-prime**

**Sample input**
   2 3 4 5
**Sample output**
   2

**Code fails for these input**
   969109092 60139073 122541116 75884463

**C program**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int d,x,y;
```

**Modular exponential (A^B)%M**

```
int power(int A, int B, int M)
{
    long long int result=1;
    while(B>0)
    {
        if(B % 2 ==1)
        {
            result=(result * A)%M;
        }
        A=(A*A)%M;
        B=B/2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Modular multiplicative inverse**

```
void extendedEuclid(int A, int B)
{
    if(B == 0)
    {
        d = A;
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        extendedEuclid(B,A%B);
        int temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp - (A/B)*y;
    }
}

int modInv(int A, int M)
{
    extendedEuclid(A,M);
    return (x%M+M)%M;
}
```

**main()**

```
int main()
{
    int A,B,C,M;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&A,&B,&C,&M);
    int inv = modInv(C,M)%M;
    printf("%d\n",inv);
    long long int p = (power(A,B,M))%M;
    printf("%d\n",p);
    long long int ans = (p * inv)%M;
    //printf("%d",((modInv(C,M)*(power(A,B,M))))%M);
    printf("%lld",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably exceeding what ints can hold. Use longs or long longs instead.

Comment: i changed these values   long long int result=1;   long long int p = (power(A,B,M))%M;    long long int ans = (p * inv)%M;  but still not working

Comment: I'm not sure about the implementation of the inverse function. Try using something like [wiki extended Euclid algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures) . The code with dual assignments like (t, newt) = ... needs to be replaced with one that uses a temp variable.

Comment: I have not followed the code but if you want the modulus `% M` of an expression that involves a constant divisor `D`, then you should use the modulus `% (M * D)` during the calculations, and finally take the proper modulus with `% M`.

Comment: What do you mean with large in numbers? Tell an example! (in the question) Which numbers do you try when algorithm fails?

Comment: Note that invmod will only work if M is prime, or at least co-prime with C.

Comment: ((A^B)%M * (inverse of B)%M)%M  this is how i am calculating my problem

Comment: @WeatherVane Using `% (M * D)` requires `M * D` to not overflow - possible needing wider math.

Comment: @chux very true. Aside, I should have said "finally divide by `D` and take the modulus with `% M`".

Comment: If `result*A` overflows, calculating `(result * A) % M` cannot be correct.   You can minimise chances by calculating `((result % M) * (A %M)) % M` but that can still overflow if `M * M` produces an overflow.    Essentially, you'll need to either store results of multiplications in a variable large enough to avoid overflow, or find another algorithm (or both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test version with fixes noted in comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int d,x,y;

int power(int A, int B, int M)
{
    long long int result=1;
    long long int S = A;            /* fix */
    while(B>0)
    {
        if(B % 2 ==1)
        {
            result=(result * S)%M;  /* fix */
        }
        S=(S*S)%M;                  /* fix */
        B=B/2;
    }
    return (int)result;
}

void extendedEuclid(int A, int B)
{
int temp;                           /* C */
    if(B == 0)
    {
        d = A;
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        extendedEuclid(B,A%B);
        temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp - (A/B)*y;
    }
}

int modInv(int A, int M)
{
    extendedEuclid(A,M);
/*  x = x%M;                        ** not needed */
    if (x < 0)                      /* fix */
        x += M;                     /* fix */
    return (x);                     /* fix */
}

int main()
{
    int A,B,C,M;                    /* C */
    int inv, p, ans;                /* C */
    A = 969109092;                  /* 2^2 × 3^2 ×7 × 1249 × 3079 */
    B =  60139073;                  /* 60139073 */
    C = 122541116;                  /* 2^2 × 1621 × 18899 */
    M =  75884463;                  /* 3^2 × 8431607 */

    inv = modInv(C,M)%M;            /* 15543920 */
    printf("%d\n",inv);
    p = power(A,B,M)%M;             /*  6704397 */
    printf("%d\n",p);
    ans = (unsigned)(((unsigned long long)p * inv)%M);  /* fix 22271562 */
    printf("%d\n",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks this code  helps me to understand my mistakes

Comment: @VikasGautam - I made changes to modInv(). There's no need for x%M, the extended Euclid algorithm already accomplishes that, except that the result may be negative. There is a need to check for x < 0 when done. During the extended Euclid algorithm, A, B, A/B, and A%B will remain positive, but x and y cycle between positive and negative numbers. To correct for `x < 0`, `x += M` as shown in the fixed code.

Answer (score 2):

Code has at least the following issues:

`int` overflow in `A*A`.  Code needs to calculate the product `A*A` using wider math.  That is why code works with small values, but not large.

```
// A=(A*A)%M;
A = ((long long)A*A) % M;
// or 
A = (1LL*A*A) % M;
```

---

Wrong print specifier.  This implies compiler warnings are not fully enabled.  Save time,  Enable them all.

```
long long int p = (power(A,B,M))%M;
// printf("%d\n",p);
printf("%lld\n",p);
```

---

Code is amiss with negative values.  Rather than patch that `int` hole, use *unsigned* types.

```
unsigned power(unsigned A, unsigned B, unsigned M) {
  unsigned long long result = 1;
  ...
```

---

Failed corner case in `power(A,0,1)`.  `result` should be 0 when `M==1`.

```
// long long int result=1;
long long int result=1%M;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of int is probably not large enough, try with long, or double.

Be careful because power returns an int not long long int

Comment: "Be careful because power returns an int not long long int" is unclear as the result should alway be in `int` range given the `%` by `int` `M`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **mod_inv** C function :

```c
// return a modular multiplicative inverse of n with respect to the modulus.
// return 0 if the linear congruence has no solutions.
unsigned mod_inv(unsigned ra, unsigned rb) {
    unsigned rc, sa = 1, sb = 0, sc, i = 0;
    if (rb > 1) do {
            rc = ra % rb;
            sc = sa - (ra / rb) * sb;
            sa = sb, sb = sc;
            ra = rb, rb = rc;
        } while (++i, rc);
    sa *= (i *= ra == 1) != 0;
    sa += (i & 1) * sb;
    return sa;
}
```

This is basically the standard algorithm, to avoid overflows the signs are stored into the **d** variable, you could use a struct to do this. Also, when **n = 1** and **mod = 0** the output is **0**, not **1**, i think we have not many computations to execute modulo **0**.

> The modular multiplicative inverse of an integer N modulo m is an integer n such as the inverse of N modulo m equals n, if a modular inverse exists then it is unique. To calculate the value of the modulo inverse, use the extended euclidean algorithm which finds solutions to the Bezout identity.

Example of usage :

```c
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned n, mod, res;

    n = 52, mod = 107;
    res = mod_inv(n, mod);
    assert(res == 35); //  35 is a solution of the linear congruence.

    n = 66, mod = 123;
    res = mod_inv(n, mod);
    assert(res == 0); // 66 does note have an inverse modulo 123.
}

/*
    n =     7 and mod = 45    then res = 13    so 1 == (   13 * 7    ) % 45   
    n =    52 and mod = 107   then res = 35    so 1 == (   35 * 52   ) % 107  
    n =   213 and mod = 155   then res = 147   so 1 == (  147 * 213  ) % 155  
    n =   392 and mod = 45    then res = 38    so 1 == (   38 * 392  ) % 45   
    n =   687 and mod = 662   then res = 53    so 1 == (   53 * 687  ) % 662  
    n =   451 and mod = 799   then res = 512   so 1 == (  512 * 451  ) % 799  
    n =  1630 and mod = 259   then res = 167   so 1 == (  167 * 1630 ) % 259  
    n =  4277 and mod = 4722  then res = 191   so 1 == (  191 * 4277 ) % 4722
*/
```

[Source](https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-MathSnip/blob/main/mod_inv.c)

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.